# How can I set the minimum time in datetimepicker based on a date that user selects there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using the jquery.datetimepicker.js from this page http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and I want to implement it in a specific way, so the user is able to choose the date starting 24 hours from a specific date.
What I did so far is:

I created a new date object based on a string that I receive from server:

```
var now = new Date("October 05, 2015 17:59:57");
```

I add 24 hours to this date:

```
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 24);
```

and later I put this logic:

```
    var dd = now.getDate();
    var mm = now.getMonth();
    var yy = now.getFullYear();
    var hh = now.getHours();

    var isPM = now.getHours() >= 12;
    var isMidday = now.getHours() == 12;
    var time = [now.getHours() - (isPM && !isMidday ? 12 : 0),
        now.getMinutes()].join(':') +
            (isPM ? ' pm' : 'am');

    var logic = function (currentDateTime) {
    if (currentDateTime.getDate() == dd && currentDateTime.getFullYear() == yy && ((currentDateTime.getMonth()) == mm)) {
            this.setOptions({
                formatTime: 'g:i A',
                format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                minDate: now,
                minTime: time
            });
    }
        else{
            this.setOptions({
                formatTime: 'g:i A',
                format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                minDate: now,
                minTime: '0:00 AM'
            });
        }


    };
```

and it almost works fine.
When user opens the datetimepicker, he sees that everyday until 6th of October is disabled (which is okay). When he chooses the 6th of October then he's able to choose time starting from 17:59:57 (24 fours after given time - which is fine). When the user clicks any day later on, e.g. 7th of October - he's able to choose any hour starting from 0:00 AM (which is cool too).

So when he chooses the date of 7th of October and hour of 0:00AM, he can switch back the date to 6th of October, and the time stays at 0:00AM - this is wrong, because it should jump into the available slot, which is for that day 17:59:57.

How can I fix it?

Here's my fiddle so far: http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/17/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the plugin contains some flaws. I came across the same bug in their examples. You can also modify the date directly in the input box and write a time before `minDate`.

My suggestion use https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker instead.

You can use the minDate option to get the same effect found [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate). And check for date changes [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not sure if my logic will fit with the new plugin, could you help me with that and show some example in the jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll try putting something up this weekend. Unfortunately I don't have time right away. Here is another script with less external files: [link](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/periodpicker/) Do try putting something up yourself before asking anyone to code it for you :)